# Python doc notation of nested quotes?

Tags: python

I'm reading python [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) of string literals, and see:

```
shortstring     ::=  "'" shortstringitem* "'" | '"' shortstringitem* '"'
longstring      ::=  "'''" longstringitem* "'''" | '"""' longstringitem* '"""'
```

what do these nested quotes mean? Why are they necessary?

Comment: The quoted items are literal elements that are part of the syntax, rather than terms that are further defined elsewhere - it's a bit messy here since the elements being quoted are themselves quote marks.  To interpret: a `shortstring` consists of zero or more `shortstringitem`s enclosed in single quotes, or zero or more `shortstringitem`s enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken directly from the paragraph below the lexical definition:

> In plain English: Both types of literals can be enclosed in matching single quotes (') or double quotes ("). They can also be enclosed in matching groups of three single or double quotes (these are generally referred to as triple-quoted strings).

In my opinion their notation is a little messier but they're attempting to show the reader that the triple quotes (single or double) act as a literal in the Python grammar.

For clarity, 
let `ƒ = """` and `∆ = '''`, then we could rewrite that expression in the grammar as

> longstring      ::=  "ƒ" longstringitem* "ƒ" | '∆' longstringitem* '∆'

Then you would write a python docstring like

```
def min(x, y):
    ∆calculates the minimum of two values x, y∆
    if x < y:
        return x:
    return y
```

or

```
def min(x, y):
    ƒcalculates the minimum of two values x, yƒ
    if x < y:
        return x:
    return y
```

Instead of the normal,

```
def min(x, y):
    """calculates the minimum of two values x, y"""
    if x < y:
        return x:
    return y
```

Of course this is a ridiculous example but I hope you get the point.